# GPIO Broken - cannot power - depower pins

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I got my pi2 this weekend and started experimenting.
Now I tried adding LEDs to the GPIOs the way I know it from arduino and all the forums do it. Pin>LED>270 Ohm>GND
I attached two: pin 17&27 (EDIT: Two separate LEDs, one to GPIO 17 and one to GPIO 27. The 17 one is always powered.)
However I cannot control them (python and bash gpio / wirepi) and one is always on, even if the pi is shut down and the SD out.

EDIT: also the 3.3V doesn't appear to be powered, the 5V one workes however.

EDIT2: I am also using the black sainSmart 40pin T breakout

This is what gpio readall gives me right after boot:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |   IN | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5V      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 1 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 1 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 1 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 1 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 1 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 1 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Is the GPIO dead?

---

EDIT:
Did some measurements, and determined a 0 resistance between GPIO 17 and the 5 V Pins.
That might be the cause.
So I guess it is dead.

Comment: No idea.  Pin 17 is the 3V3 rail.  You have no control over the power and ground pins.  You can only control pins connected to GPIO.

Comment: GPIO 17 and 27 are shown as inputs in that list.  What command(s) are you using to set their values?

Comment: All the Pi GPIO are 3V3.  NEVER connect them to 5V.  I suggest you search for an introductory on-line tutorial.

Comment: When you say GPIO 17 which PHYSICAL pin (the central two columns of numbers) do you mean? **17**: which is as Joan says is a 3v3 SUPPLY rail and not controlled by software or **11**: which is pin GPIO 17 as far as the Broadcom ARM core is concerned? Similarly for GPIO 27 do you mean **13** or **36**.

Answer (score 1):

Think you have GPIO 17 (on physical PIN 11) confused with PIN 17; also PIN 27 is not a ground but ID_SD. Ground pins are as follows 6, 9, 14, 20, 25, 30, 34, 39. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant GPIO 17 and 27. They are two separate leds

Answer (score 1):

Try To Access Pin's Using Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash
#GPIO numbers should be from this list
#0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25

#Note that the GPIO numbers that you program here refer to the pins
#of the BCM2835 and *not* the numbers on the pin header. 
#So, if you want to activate GPIO7 on the header you should be 
#using GPIO4 in this script. Likewise if you want to activate GPIO0
#on the header you should be using GPIO17 here.

#Set up GPIO 4 and set to output:
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction

#Set up GPIO 7 and set to input
echo "7" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/direction

#Write output
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value

#Read from input
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value 

#Clean up
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
echo "7" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

Comment: I am getting [this](http://pastebin.com/DLEQwj7H) response - How do I permit the ports?

Comment: try in root mode

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/5kbDDLTV), If the LEDs are supposed to do something; they don't

Comment: what i gave is a example of accessing GPIO using shell script, you have to make change GPIO no in script according to your need.